# No heat in car, low coolant vs heater core

Tags: overheating, heater

Car has no heat and temperature gauge creeps up very close to the overheating zone especially when car is not moving.  Suspected that low coolant due to slow leak was to blame, and in the past adding more coolant has fixed this.

Recently, there's been no heat despite temperature gauge in the normal operating zone. Is it possible that the heater core is bad, and would there be any additional signs or symptoms if this were the case?

Additional info (most likely unrelated):  Front blower hasn't been working in a long time.  Occasionally hitting a bump in the road caused it to briefly start working again.  Rear blower works fine ie can hear motor blowing, but cold air only

Comment: You should add which car you have, someone may be very familiar with it.

Comment: I'd suggest you should have your thermostat checked. In a lot of vehicles if the thermostat stays closed, no water is being diverted into the heater core. It could also be why the engine is nearly overheating.

Comment: A possible problem in addition to the plugged heater core.  You may have ended up with an air bubble trapped in the heater core which is preventing coolant from flowing through it.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Wouldn't the check engine light be on if bad thermostat?  No check engine light in my case

Comment: @HandyHowie 2008 Dodge Grand Caravan

Comment: I'm thinking about starting with a coolant flush as I haven't done this in a long time and not an expensive repair

Comment: @publicwireless - No CEL from a thermostat issue.

Answer (score 1):

After dealing with this issue for a long time (temperature gauge on verge of overheating when stopped in traffic), it seems like the issue was finally solved when the hoses to the heater core ruptured, and started spraying hot coolant.  As it was now obvious where the problem resided, I got the heater core hoses replaced and it fixed the issue on this Dodge Grand Caravan